# html table with Collapsible rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make html table rows collapsible. following is what i have tried so far, but i am not getting the expected result.
I don't know where i am doing wrong, any help is appreciated.
This is the Html Code:

```
<body>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">Option A</a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">Option B</a>
  <a href="RmsLogoutServlet">Logout</a>
</div><br>
<div class="divtabletree" id="divtabletree"></div>
</body>
```

This is JavaScript and jquery Code to display data from database in a table format by making an ajax call to "**ExampleServlet**" servlet.
I think the problem is in below code only, because the data is displaying properly it's only the row collapsible thing which is not working here.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var tkid;
    var id;
    var datatable = '<table id="datatable" class="datatable"><tr><th>Part No.</th><th>Description</th><th>Data Sheet</th><th>Order Link</th><th></th></tr>';
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "ExampleServlet",              
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) 
        {                
            var info1=json.JSonDataFinal;   
            $.each(info1, function(index, element) 
            {
                var info = element.JsonData;
                var tabletemp;
                var tablerows;
                var tablerowssub;
                $.each(info, function(index, element) 
                {   
                    if(tkid!=element.tokenid)
                    {
                        datatable = datatable + '<tr class=header><td colspan=5>Header</td></tr>';
                        datatable = datatable + '<tr><td>'+element.partno+'</td><td>'+element.description+'</td><td>'+element.datasheet+'</td><td>'+element.orderlink+'</td><td>'+element.tokenid+'</td></tr>';
                        tkid = element.tokenid;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        datatable = datatable + '<tr><td>'+element.partno+'</td><td>'+element.description+'</td><td>'+element.datasheet+'</td><td>'+element.orderlink+'</td><td>'+element.tokenid+'</td></tr>';
                    }                   
                });
            });
            datatable = datatable + '</table>'
            $("#divtabletree").append(datatable);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            ;
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('tr').hide().filter(function () 
    {
        return $(this).find('td[colspan]').length;
    }).addClass('header').css('display', 'table-row').click(function () 
        {
            $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').css('display', function (i, v) 
            {
                return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
            });
        });
});
```

The problem here is when i click on the header row nothing happens.
Where as the rows beneath the header row until next header row should be toggled when clicked on a header row.

Comment: "Nothing happens" is not a very descriptive error description. Did you try to debug your code? Like using the browser developer tools to inspect whether the `display` property is changed or whether the click listener is called at all? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: I tried debugging, it works as expected only when debugged in browser.Where as if directly run the same code it won't work.

Comment: looks like the click listener is not getting called! How do i tackle this? Any suggestion?